# Load more when scroll to bottom like facebook(Jsp or Servlets)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, mysql, servlets

Yes, I want something like Facebook post. But i'm unable to find any good resources for Java.

I'm making my project using `Servlets` and `Jsp` technologies. It has lots of contents in Database. I'm fetching it using `Select *..` But i want to put something like Facebook for Loading more contents when scroll to bottom.

Problem is that i don't know anything about `Ajax`, So please how to implement it on my servlets project during fetching the data, At least give me an ideas.

HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of technology/language, your process goes something like:
1) Request x records from service and display
2) When user reaches end of x records, fetch x more records from web service with offset = x
3) Display those records

Repeat.

Comment: And as noted by down votes, it is a poor question because you've posted no code aside from a select statement.